# Multiple Declare statements in SQL

Tags: sql-server

1 job ago, my boss said he found an article saying that multiple declare statements inside our stored procedures was bad because (I think) the compiler stops and restarts again on each declare.  Ever since, I have always said that there should only be 1 declare statement (unless you need to make a table variable) in each stored procedure.

While I'm 1/2 way decent at writing stored procedures in SQL Server, I don't know how to see how SQL actually works in this respect.

So my question is, can someone either point me towards an article or give some proof about whether or not multiple declare statements in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (or above) is bad for the performance of the stored procedure?

Comment: What does "stop and restart" the compiler mean?

Comment: Your previous boss was making stuff up. That claim is complete rubbish.

Comment: The only thing remotely close to this I can think of is mixing DDL (Data Definition Language) and DML (Data Manipulation Language) in a stored procedure causes recompiles. So put all your DDL statements at the beginning of the stored procedure, and then follow it with your DML.

Answer (score 2):

That is non-sense. I could see making the commandment that all declares should be in one spot (I personally like that), but for organization and not performance arguments. A single declare commandment would certainly enforce that usage.

As evidence, I just tested 1000 individual declares versus a single declare with 1000 values and the times were identical.